# Laravel's XSRF-TOKEN never changes

Tags: reactjs, axios, laravel-sanctum, csrf-token, laravel-10

I installed Laravel v10.13.0 (PHP v8.2.5) with Breeze & React starter kit and followed the official documentation to implement API authentication with Sanctum and Axios (https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/sanctum#spa-authentication). The application itself works perfectly fine. The weird thing is that the XSRF-TOKEN never changes. On different browsers, different computers my site is setting exactly the same string in the cookies.

Is there a setting I'm missing?